# Jquery remove and $(this)

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem with `remove()` method. I can't remove `$(this)` object. My code is:

```
$(".submit_add_type").live("click", function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var type_value = parent.children('.type_value').val();
        var type_name = parent.children('.type_name').val();
        var parent2 = parent.parent();
        var permission = parent2.attr('id').replace('perm_types_', '');

        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/ajax/permission_type_add", type: "POST", cache: false,
            data: {
                permission: permission,
                type_value: type_value,
                type_name: type_name,
            },
            success: function(text) {
                if(text.substr(0,2) == "ok") {
                    var id = text.replace('ok|', '');

                    $(this).remove();
                    parent.append('<input class="submit" type="submit" name="" value="edytuj" id="edit_type_'+ id +'" /> <input class="submit delete_type" type="submit" name="" value="usuń" id="delete_type_'+ id +'" />')

                } else {
                    alert(text);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

When I change `$(this).remove();` on `$(".submit_add_type").remove();` it works perfectly. What could be wrong?

The thing is, there can be other objects with this `submit_add_type` class and I want to remove only a particular one.

Comment: That should work fine. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMjrq/ Does the other code in your function run?

Comment: Please share the code you've omitted with `[...]`. I suspect it is relevant, since the simple snippet works. http://jsfiddle.net/GQ9Z7/1

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you are trying to do. Perhaps there is a syntactic or other error that makes your code not run?

Comment: I have edited to full version of my code

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos check my answer below, I believe these gentlemen were correct and the code I posted should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon entering the `success` function, `$(this)` becomes the `text` argument.  Change it to something like:

```
$(".submit_add_type").live("click", function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    ...

    $(_this).remove();

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the value of `this` changes inside the `$.ajax` callback.  You need to save `this` as a variable and then use that inside the callback.

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(){
      $(that).remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some other issue going on there, when I try it out in jsFiddle, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uLVR5/

It looks like you have things happening before the .remove() call, is it a substantial amount?

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and comments above?

Comment: Looks like about 6 min. ;-) Sorry, I realized after that I should have posted this as a comment and didn't refresh the page prior to see if there were other comments.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is refering to the object "{url:"...", data:"..."}" so it does not make sense to have "$(this).remove()" where you put it.

Use:

```
$(".submit_add_type").live("click", function() {
        var elem= $(this), parent = elem.parent();
        var type_value = parent.children('.type_value').val();
        var type_name = parent.children('.type_name').val();
        var parent2 = parent.parent();
        var permission = parent2.attr('id').replace('perm_types_', '');

        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/ajax/permission_type_add", type: "POST", cache: false,
            data: {
                permission: permission,
                type_value: type_value,
                type_name: type_name,
            },
            success: function(text) {
                if(text.substr(0,2) == "ok") {
                    var id = text.replace('ok|', '');

                    elem.remove();
                    parent.append('<input class="submit" type="submit" name="" value="edytuj" id="edit_type_'+ id +'" /> <input class="submit delete_type" type="submit" name="" value="usuń" id="delete_type_'+ id +'" />')

                } else {
                    alert(text);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```